# Finding congruent triangle to prove equality of two segments

Tags: geometry

Given $\triangle ABC$, from point M lying inside ABC, are descended perpendiculars to the sides $AC$ and $BC$, point Q is mid point for side $AB$, $\angle MAC = \angle MBC$, prove that PQ = NQ. Here is drawing:[image]

The only way I can think of proving this is by finding congruent triangles, which have $QN$ and $QP$ for sides, but I don't see such congruent triangles, nor other way to prove that the segments are equal .

Comment: Do you want similarity, or congruence? The former doesn't immediately imply equality of sides.

Comment: Yeah congruence, I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice solution through complex numbers. $MNA$ and $MPB$ are similar triangles, hence if we embed the construction in the complex plane by putting the origin at $Q$, we may assume $A=-1,B=1$ and:

$$ P = (M-1)z+1, \qquad N = (M+1)\overline{z}-1. $$
$\|P\|=\|N\|$ follows by recognizing a [Blaschke factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlaschkeFactor.html), since $z=\sin(\theta)e^{-i\theta}$ for some $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

In elementary terms, we may set $AM=x,MB=y,AQ=2$ and $\widehat{MAN}=\widehat{MBP}=\theta$.
It follows that $BP=y\cos\theta, AN=x\cos\theta$ and by the cosine theorem:

$$ QP^2-QN^2 = (y^2-x^2)\cos^2\theta-2y\cos\theta\cos B+2x\cos\theta\cos A. $$
By applying the sine theorem to the triangle $MAB$ and the cosine sum formulas, you may easily check that the previous expression equals zero.

Comment: Your answer may be grate, but I didn't understand a word from it. My background is only high-school math(from the system in eastern Europe).

Comment: @Planet_Earth: there is an addendum.

Comment: Splendid solutions (+1)